# I was trying to install numpy using pipenv with the code "pipenv install python" but it kept on coming up with errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pipenv

I was trying to install numpy using pipenv with the code "pipenv install python" but it kept on coming up with errors. Below is the last output I got in my terminal while trying to install. Could someone please help me debug this.

When I was attempting to install numpy I got the following error:
Locking Failed!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 425, in _error_catcher
yield
File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 507, in read
data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
data = self.__fp.read(amt)
File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 454, in read
n = self.readinto(b)
File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 498, in readinto
n = self.fp.readinto(b)
File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 669, in
readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/users/calibest/appdata/local/programs/python/python38-32/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 807, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/users/calibest/appdata/local/programs/python/python38-32/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 802, in main
    _main(parsed.pre, parsed.clear, parsed.verbose, parsed.system, parsed.write,
  File "c:/users/calibest/appdata/local/programs/python/python38-32/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 785, in _main
    resolve_packages(pre, clear, verbose, system, write, requirements_dir, packages)
  File "c:/users/calibest/appdata/local/programs/python/python38-32/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 746, in resolve_packages
    results, resolver = resolve(
  File "c:/users/calibest/appdata/local/programs/python/python38-32/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 728, in resolve
    return resolve_deps(
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 1378, in resolve_deps
    results, hashes, markers_lookup, resolver, skipped = actually_resolve_deps(
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 1093, in actually_resolve_deps
    resolver.resolve()
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 808, in resolve
    results = self.resolver.resolve(max_rounds=environments.PIPENV_MAX_ROUNDS)
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\piptools\resolver.py", line 180, in resolve
    has_changed, best_matches = self._resolve_one_round()
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\piptools\resolver.py", line 268, in _resolve_one_round
    their_constraints.extend(self._iter_dependencies(best_match))
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\piptools\resolver.py", line 383, in _iter_dependencies
    dependencies = self.repository.get_dependencies(ireq)
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\piptools\repositories\pypi.py", line 226, in get_dependencies
    legacy_results = self.get_legacy_dependencies(ireq)
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\piptools\repositories\pypi.py", line 347, in get_legacy_dependencies
    results, ireq = self.resolve_reqs(
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\piptools\repositories\pypi.py", line 303, in resolve_reqs
    results = resolver._resolve_one(reqset, ireq)
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 339, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 287, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 473, in prepare_linked_requirement
    local_path = unpack_url(
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 282, in unpack_url
    return unpack_http_url(
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 158, in unpack_http_url
    from_path, content_type = _download_http_url(
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 303, in _download_http_url
    for chunk in download.chunks:
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 15, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 564, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 529, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\calibest\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\patched\notpip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 430, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pipenv.patched.notpip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Comment: You might want to use a more specific title that would help draw the attention from someone who ran into this problem, e.g., "Why do I get timeout errors trying to install Numpy".  In addition, if you are trying to install Numpy, you should just use that in your command `pipenv install numpy`

Answer (score 0):

Python should be installed by default. Try using `pipenv  --py` to see the details of where the python interpreter is installed.